# Determine if a std::string has all of the same character

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings

I'm working on an algorithm to determine if a `std::string` has all of the same character. Here is what I have:

```
bool string_has_all_of_the_same_chars(const std::string& s) {
    return std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [&s](char ch) { return ch == s[0]; });
}
```

Are there any improvements that can be made to this? I am guaranteed by another function that `s` is not empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could simply use [`find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of)

```
bool string_has_all_of_the_same_chars(const std::string& s) {
    return s.find_first_not_of(s[0]) == std::string::npos;
}
```

*Update:*

This works only, when the string is not empty. A complete version would also test [`empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty)

```
bool string_has_all_of_the_same_chars(const std::string& s) {
    return s.empty() || s.find_first_not_of(s[0]) == std::string::npos;
}
```

Instead of `s[0]`, one could also use [`s.front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) or [`*s.begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin).

Comment: You could use `s.front()` instead of `s[0]`.